# Rails controller and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I have a form that adds codes to an appointment in rails. There are 2 types of codes, regular codes that get added straight to the apt and wildcard codes that return a list of codes that contain the query (ex. 800* returns anything with 800 in it).

What I need to do is have any regular codes get added to the appointment and return the appointment page if no wildcard codes are selected. If wildcard codes are selected, I need to render a partial that toggleslides out with the search results. If both wildcard and regular codes are selected I need the toggleslide but also have the regular codes updated on the codes table on the page.

The problem I'm having is when just regular codes are selected, the toggleslide is still being called and populated with the appointment page in it.

I have the form that does this set to remote and in a js file I have the ajax response do the toggleslide and populate it with the response. Is there a way to override the ajax response in the controller and just redirect to the appointment page if no wildcard codes are selected?

Or is there a better way to do all this? I tried using a js template but keep getting a 406 error. Or I fix the 406 error by removing any respond_to calls but the toggleslide doesn't get called.

In my js file in my assets.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#custom_codes_form_1").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $('#my_lists_modal_1').hide();
    $('#search_code_results').html(data);
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $('#search_code_results').show('blind', {direction: "left"});
  });
  return false;
});
```

In my controller. @all_codes is the list of codes returned on a search query.
This is in the add_code_list_codes method:

```
if !@all_codes.nil?
    render :partial => "/encounter/code_search_results", :content_type => 'text/html', :locals => {:codes => @codes, :apt => @apt, :all_codes => @all_codes, :diagnoses_search => true, :type => @type}
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to encounter_show_path(:id => @apt.id)}
  end
end
```

Here's the form.

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => :encounter, :action => :add_code_list_codes, :id => @apt.id}, :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => "custom_codes_form_#{cl.id}", :remote => true ) do %>
 <% CodeType.by_name.all.each do |ct| %>
   <h4 class="small_bottom_margin"><%= ct.display_name %></h4>
   <div class="control-group">
      <% cl.code_list_items.all_by_code_type(ct.id).each do |cc| %>
         <%= label_tag :codes, :class => 'checkbox' do %>
         <% if cc.code %>
           <%= check_box_tag 'codes[]', cc.id %>  <strong><%= cc.code.code %></strong> - <%= cc.name_override ? cc.name_override : cc.code.name %>
         <% else %>
           <%= check_box_tag 'codes[]', cc.id %>  <strong><%= cc.search_criteria %></strong> - Wildcard
         <% end %>
       <% end %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
 <%= submit_tag("Add Selected Charges", :class => 'btn', 'data-disable-with' => "Adding Charges") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the form?